# Installing React js giving a error. name not provided in package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and i am trying to install it from the official website.
I have cloned the repo and When i try to run `npm install -g create-react-app`
I getting the following error. What am i doing wrong??

```
D:\React-New>npm install -g create-react-app
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install D:\React-New\create-react-app
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "create-react-app"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0

npm ERR! No name provided in package.json
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-12T13_40_59_226Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Install node v6 and update npm (npm install npm@latest -g)

Comment: I have node v 7.10.0 and npm 4.2.0. Still, i have that error.

Comment: v6 is long term supported version of Node.js. I've had this problem before it was either that or npm which is now v5.2

Answer (score 1):

If people are finding this, this is because there isn't a name in your package.json. Might be that you don't have any package.json at all.

Run "npm init" in your directory, to fast create a package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

To start a fresh react project, put this in your cmd:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html